# Remove all text before last space in text file from CLI

Tags: command-line, sed, regex

I want to remove everything before the last space in a text file from the CLI

Example text:

```
2015-03-02 21:34:15      20480 dump-2015-03-02-21-34.tar
```

The string that should remain is `dump-2015-03-02-21-34.tar`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a lot of choice using the command line:

```
$ echo "2015-03-02 21:34:15      20480 dump-2015-03-02-21-34.tar" | cut -c32-
dump-2015-03-02-21-34.tar

$ echo "2015-03-02 21:34:15      20480 dump-2015-03-02-21-34.tar" | sed 's/.* //'
dump-2015-03-02-21-34.tar

$ echo "2015-03-02 21:34:15      20480 dump-2015-03-02-21-34.tar" | grep -oP "\S+$"
dump-2015-03-02-21-34.tar

$ echo "2015-03-02 21:34:15      20480 dump-2015-03-02-21-34.tar" | awk {'print $NF'}
dump-2015-03-02-21-34.tar

$ echo "2015-03-02 21:34:15      20480 dump-2015-03-02-21-34.tar" | perl -pe 's/.* //'
dump-2015-03-02-21-34.tar

$ echo "2015-03-02 21:34:15      20480 dump-2015-03-02-21-34.tar" | rev | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | rev
dump-2015-03-02-21-34.tar
```

Answer (score 5):

`sed` is by default greedy, so just remove everything until the last space:

```
sed 's/.* //'
```

or use this `awk` idiom:

```
awk '$0=$NF'
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `grep`:

```
echo "2015-03-02 21:34:15      20480 dump-2015-03-02-21-34.tar" | grep -Eo "[^ ]+$"
```

You can also use `tr` and `cut` together:

```
echo "2015-03-02 21:34:15      20480 dump-2015-03-02-21-34.tar" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f4
```

Why should `python` be left behind:

```
python2 -c 'print "2015-03-02 21:34:15      20480 dump-2015-03-02-21-34.tar".split()[3]'
```

All of the above produce output: `dump-2015-03-02-21-34.tar`